# Load error in nopCommerce's shipping address form

Tags: javascript, view, nopcommerce

In nopCommerce I want that when I click next btn in shipping address form without selecting country and state I should redirect to page with validation but when I click on next btn it is redirecting to dropdown option.

To solve this I have written below code but it is not working as required.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sg612.png)[[page when I[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W0Njm.png) click next without selecting country and state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aebiP.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7sR1d.png)

I tried below lines of code using javascript:

```
window.onload = function () {
        if ($(".validation-summary-errors").length > 0) {
            // If validation is fired, show the shipping address form and uncheck the pickup in store checkbox
            $('#shipping-addresses-form').show();
            $("#@Html.IdFor(model => model.PickupInStore)").prop("checked", false);

            // Log a message to check if this code is running
            console.log("Validation errors detected. Handling dropdown and checkbox.");

            // Select the "ship to home address" option in the dropdown
            $("#pickup-points-select").val("ship_to_home");
        }
    }
```

First I checked whether validation is fired
If above condition is true then shipping address form with `Ship_to_home_address` option should be selected from dropdown.
But above is not working as expected.